# Will the query plan be changed on different data size?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

Suppose the data distribution does not change, For a same query, only dataset is enlarged a time, will the time taken also becomes 1 time? If the data distribution does not change, will the query plan change if in theory?

Comment: Yes, the query plan could change (at least with any sensible query optimizer).

Comment: why? since the data distribution does not change, each predicates filter capability does not change, the parameters does not change, why does the query plan change ? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: By "data distribution" do you mean that the data is static or that the statistical properties remain the same?

Comment: If the distribution stays the same the plan will change once it hits the work_mem setting, and maybe again once shared_buffers / effective_cache_size limits are hit.

Comment: suppose I have two datasets, in each of them the distribution of values are same, this is what I mean same distribution @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @joop in my test, the parameters you said have impacted the plan and I want to label yours as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.  You have record on one page and an index.  Consider the query:

```
select t.*
from table t
where col = x;
```

And, assume you have an index on `col`.  With one record, the fastest way is to simply read the record and check the `where` clause.  You could have 200 records on the page, so the selectivity of the query might be less than 1%.

One of the key considerations that a SQL optimizer makes in choosing an algorithm is the number of expected page reads.  So, if you have a query like the above, the engine might think "I have to read all pages in the table anyway, so let me just do a full table scan and ignore the index."  Note that this will be true when the data is on a single page.

This generalizes to other operations as well.  If all the records in your data fit on one data page, then "slow" algorithms are often the best or close enough to the best.  So, nested loop joins might be better than using indexes, hash-based, or sort-merge based joins.  Similarly, a sort-based aggregation might be better than other methods.

Alas, I am not as familiar with the Postgres query optimizer as I am with SQL Server and Oracle.  I have definitely encountered changes in execution plans in those databases as data grew.

Comment: Data distribution is not supposed to change. So if you start with one record and then keep the data distribution you will always end with table scan because index scan to select every record doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JakubKania . . . I fixed the example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the query plan may still change even if the data is completely static, though it probably won't.

The autovaccum daemon will `ANALYZE` your tables and generate new statistics. This usually happens only when they've changed, but may happen for other reasons (wrap-around prevention vacuum, etc).

The statistics include a *random sampling* to collect common values for a histogram. Being random, the outcome may be somewhat different each time.

To reduce the chances of plans shifting for a static dataset, you probably want to increase the statistics target on the table's columns and re-ANALYZE. Don't set it too high though, as the query planner has to read those histograms when it makes planning decisions, and bigger histograms mean slightly more planning time.

If your table is growing continuously but the distribution isn't changing then you *want* the planner to change plans at various points. A 1000-row table is almost certainly best accessed by doing a sequential scan; an index scan would be a waste of time and effort. You certainly don't want a million row table being scanned sequentially unless you're retrieving a majority of the rows, though. So the planner should - and does - adjust its decisions based not only on the data distribution, but the overall row counts.

Comment: thanks, If I have two static dataset, one has 512 rows another has 1024 rows, both have a same distribution. will the query plan change much? or it should be almost twice time longer for the second dataset? @Craig Ringer

Comment: Generally the plan wouldn't differ between those. You're more likely to see plans differ when data set sizes vary by orders of magnitude - 1000 rows vs 10,000 rows or 100,000 rows. However, that doesn't mean query times are going to be linear doubling just because the dataset doubles. Often the query execution time won't go up at all, or will only go up a tiny amount for a big increase in dataset size.